# Decrease footnotes margin in moderncv

Tags: spacing, footnotes, moderncv, footmisc

I'm beginning with LaTeX, so this question is may be obvious. When using `moderncv` package, if I add footnotes to my document, the footnotes take too much space.

How can I decrease the footnotes margin?

Here is a miminal example (MWE) to reproduce the problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}

\usepackage[bottom,norule]{footmisc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX\footnotemark[1], YYY\footnotemark[2], ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX\footnotemark[1], YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\footnotetext[1]{First note}
\footnotetext[2]{Second note}

\end{document}
```

Comment: These footnotes may be right, but for my use case (my cv have to fit in a single page), the footer takes too much space.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you are already loading the `geometry` package, adjust the values for `bmargin` (the bottom margin) and `footnotesep` (the separation between the bottom of text body and the top of footnote text); for example:

```
\usepackage[scale=0.75,bmargin=1cm,footnotesep=1cm]{geometry}
```

Comment: Thanks @gonzalo-medina, this works great! I also had to set a tmargin value.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you mean by the footnote takes to much space. If you want the footnotes further down on the page, you can try to add this command on the first page:

```
\enlargethispage{6\baselineskip}
```

This will only work if you do not fill the first page with text.

Answer (score 1):

Gonzalo Medina's answer allows to play on the margins of the document. If you wish to keep the same margins and ensure that your footnotes end up in the footer, you can do the following:

```
% Ensure the footnotes are pushed to the end of the page, whether it is full or not
\vfill
% Add the footer to the content of the page
\enlargethispage{\footskip}
\footnotetext[1]{First note}
\footnotetext[2]{Second note}
```

Additionaly, you can use both this method and Gonzalo Medina's to ensure the footnotes are all the way down (with `\vfill`) and reduce the margins (using `geometry`).